# What is the dagger at the bottom of this photo?

Tags: identification, weapons

Could anyone assist with possibly identifying the blade at the bottom of this picture? I know that it is incredibly sharp and maybe a Jambiya. I am trying to date it and also place its original geography in order to ascertain its value for a friend. It belonged to her late husband.

[image: unknown edged weapon]

Comment: There are three blades in the picture, which one do you want to identify? The title is referring to the dagger but the tag is for a sword. If it's the dagger, then an image of the blade out of the scabbard would be useful.

Comment: The one at the bottom of the photograph. Thank you.

Comment: Without seeing the blade, it's a koummya, a Moroccan/Berber dagger. Sometimes people call them Jambiyas, but for me the later need to have a very marked spine and a shorter y more curved blade

Comment: Thank you @CarlosMartin